# Does pushing someone into difficult terrain require extra "movement"?

Tags: dnd-5e, forced-movement, terrain

The [Way of the Open Hand monk](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/monk#WayoftheOpenHand) gets the Open Hand Technique feature at 3rd level, which allows the following effect as one of the options when using Flurry of Blows:

> Whenever you hit a creature with one of the attacks granted by your Flurry of Blows, you can impose one of the following effects on that target:
>
> [...]
>
> - It must make a Strength saving throw. If it fails, you can push it up to 15 feet away from you.

**Is the distance I can push a creature using the Open Hand Monk's Flurry of Blows feature reduced if I push the target through difficult terrain?**

Comment: Related: [Would Your Speed Be Reduced If You Drag A Grappled Opponent Through Difficult Terrain?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/77415)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

## No, pushing distance does not interact with difficult terrain at all

Difficult terrain states:

> Every foot of movement in difficult terrain costs 1 extra foot.

However, pushing does not involve the spending of movement. The Open Hand technique says:

> If it fails [a strength saving throw], you can push it up to 15 feet away from you.

The pushed creature does not use their movement in response to being pushed, nor in fact, does the distance of the push depend on any speed or movement or require the spending of either. Since you are not spending movement, there is no way to spend extra movement. Thus, the push distance is completely independent of the mechanics for speed and movement and thus has no interaction with difficult terrain at all.

Comment: Maybe this is clearer in the full quote of the mechanic, but the word "movement" is not capitalized in the difficult terrain quote. Is it really talking about the Move action specifically, rather than a general idea of moving across difficult terrain which would include pushing?

Comment: @Winterborne: Move is not an action in 5e. You just have movement on your turn to spend equal to your speed. So move or movement are never, to my knowledge, capitalized like actions are. Consider this: if  a creature was under the effects of a condition that reduced their speed (and thus movement) to 0 could you push them? Of course, because pushing and movement have no bearing on each other.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'm confusing my game systems again.

Comment: Why are you certain that "costs 1 extra foot" only applies to "when using movement"?  It says it costs "1 extra foot"; these are the same units as the push are in.  We can test this: "costing 1 extra foot of push" is both grammatically correct and clear, as would "costing 1 extra foot of movement" which would unambiguously agree with your reading.

Comment: @Yakk: because it literally says: "Every foot of **movement**...costs 1 extra foot."

Comment: @Rubiksmoose Ah, you are reading "foot of movement" there as a compound  keyword.  Fair!  Can you highlight that?

Comment: @Yakk I mean I don't necessarily consider that whole phrase to be a keyword or anything... but if it makes sense to you I think we are on the same page. I'm not sure bolding half of such a short quote is going to be helpful though.