# How can solo Crusher Swarmkeeper best leverage forced movement?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, optimization, forced-movement, environmental-hazards

The Swarmkeeper¹ Ranger’s Gathering Swarm¹ feature applies one of three effects to one attack each round, one of which is forcing the target of the attack to move 15 feet if they fail a Strength save. The Crusher feat allows you to move the target of your bludgeoning-damage attack 5 feet, no save, also once per turn. Using *magic stone*,² I can make Wisdom-based ranged attacks that deal bludgeoning damage, allowing me to maximize both my accuracy and my save DC. So I can push people around.

What or where am I pushing them? There may be environmental hazards I can leverage, or with a party, perhaps my party can create some. But what about solo, when the environment isn’t inherently hazardous? Ultimately I’m talking about one cantrip, one feat, and three class levels to achieve these features—there’s a lot of room there to potentially add synergy. Is there some synergy I can build into the same character which rewards my ability shove people around? The big concern I have here is actions—if I multiclass to access spells that create hazardous zones, that usually means an action to produce them, and then I can get to shoving.

Good answers will (probably) point options in one or more of these flavors:

- Ways to generate hazardous zones that are especially action-efficient. Things you can create as a bonus action (or no action?), or things that are permanent (or long-duration) and portable, perhaps. For example, if forced movement provoked attacks of opportunity ([it doesn’t](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/120959/4563)), then a companion that can take opportunity attacks would be a great solution, since I could push enemies past the companion and trigger those attacks.

  That approach *might* still be viable for this, if I can force their movement away from me and then they have to move on their own turn back towards me and trigger opportunity attacks. But it seems in that case that most are probably just going to eliminate my companion. Maybe there’s a situation, though, where the “companion” is not really attack-able—a spell effect, perhaps.
- Ways to turn very-common environmental features into hazards. For example, D&D 3.5e had a Dungeoncrasher³ Fighter, which could deal very high damage by shoving people into walls. Walls are common enough environmental features to feel comfortable relying on them.
- Ways to directly punish movement—effects that deal more damage the more you move, perhaps. Again, obviously, strong preference for those that are compatible with forced movement, though if I force them away and then they have to walk to me maybe that’s enough.

Any Wizards of the Coast-published material is acceptable, with the exception of *Unearthed Arcana* material that has since been superseded by later *Unearthed Arcana* material or official publication. Please note the sources of any material used. I am specifically seeking D&D 5e expertise here—I want to see judgment and analysis of how effective a proposal is, what its potential pros and cons are. One big part of this is going to be comparing the build against other builds that can do similar things—for example, if suggesting a build that relies on opportunity attacks being provoked as the target moves back towards me, that should be compared against other builds that use, for example, *dissonant whispers* so that the target provokes coming and going. Likewise, do Swarmkeeper,¹ Crusher,¹ and *magic stone*² even make sense when I could just go with *eldritch blast* and Repelling Blast⁴ and/or Grasp of Hadar²?

1. <sub>*Tasha’s Cauldron of Everything*</sub>
2. <sub>*Xanathar’s Guide to Everything*</sub>
3. <sub>*Dungeonscape*, a 3.5e supplement</sub>
4. <sub>*Player’s Handbook*</sub>

Comment: If someone creates a multiclass build, is there a level at which you wouldn't delay your primary class progression? This is probably a bit more important if you aren't going to 20.but would help provide a good constraint for builds to make sure you still get the things you want out of the swarm keeper.

Comment: Should we also assume yours stats allow for any multiclass? Or do you have stats we can use?

Comment: @NautArch The goal is to maximize the solo effectiveness of the forced movement on attack from Gathered Swarm—whatever build makes that happen is fine. The character hasn’t been created yet so everything remains flexible.

Comment: Do you have a preferred range for when the build would go online?

Comment: @NautArch The ideal build would be functional/viable for the most levels possible—so come online early, but also continue to grow and scale as long as possible. A build that comes online at 3rd but has become outclassed by 9th and lacks options to grow is worse than a build that comes online at 6th and remains viable through 20th, for example.

Comment: Gotcha. This is a bit too wide for me, but hopefully others can help! Cool idea :)

Comment: @KRyan You've specified that the crusher feat doesn't have a once per turn restriction, and I can't link to the dndbeyond example for this, but I'm pretty sure it does (at least now) have that limitation - unless I'm misunderstanding the wording

Comment: @Whambulance ...right you are. _Why_ do my eyes keep skipping over that? Did it with both Crusher and Gathering Swarm.

Comment: You could also use the *shillelagh* cantrip to deal Wisdom-based bludgeoning damage in melee, as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for the *spike growth* spell.  This is a second-level ranger spell (available at level five) which says:

> The ground in a 20-foot radius centered on a point within range twists and sprouts hard spikes and thorns. The area becomes difficult terrain for the duration. When a creature moves into or within the area, it takes 2d4 piercing damage for every 5 feet it travels.

This lets you convert your 20ft of push into 8d4 damage (average 20).

You could stand near the center of this damage zone.  In theory, against a single opponent, you could get into a situation where you push them back 20ft (see: [pushing ignores difficult terrain](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/130692/does-pushing-someone-into-difficult-terrain-require-extra-movement)) and then they have to spend 40ft of movement to get back into melee range, and both directions inflict 2d4 damage per 5ft of movement.

In terms of damage, you'd be looking at 1d6 (magic stone) +4 (WIS) + 8d4 (spikes) = 27.5 average damage.  Or 47.5 average damage, if the monster ran back at you across the spikes!

For comparison, a fifth-level ranger might do 2*(1d8 (longbow) + 4 (DEX)) + 1d8 (Colossus Slayer) + 1d6 (Hunter's Mark) = 25 average damage, at a higher attack bonus due to archery stance.

Optional ways to improve this include:

- multiclass to sorcerer to get *quicken spell* so you can deploy your spike growth more quickly
- invite your spellcaster friends to use *moonbeam* and *spirit guardians* and *wall of fire* so you have more damage zones to punt creatures into

Of course this doesn't work if you miss, or if they make their save.  It works poorly if you have disadvantage because they're standing next to you.
It doesn't work at all against ranged attackers or fliers, and it scales poorly if you're attacked by more than one opponent.

Overall this approach seems bad, simply because there are so many situations where it doesn't work, and then you've invested a lot of resources into a trick that you can't use.

(Also, it's often a bad idea to create a character with a trick that trivializes encounters, because many DMs will react by generating encounters where you can't use your trick.)

However I do think there's the potential for a good build that went Swarmkeeper Ranger, did not go for high WIS or Magic Stone, but did keep a *spike growth* effect on the battlefield for use whenever the swarm ability activates.  This comes at a cost because it replaces your concentration for *hunter's mark* but seems likely to be worth it.

Comment: You're talking about the *spike growth* spell, right? (You mention *spike stones* a few times, which I don't think is a spell in 5e.)